# Запуск Firebird из-под Linux

Tags: linux, firebird

Получил "в наследство" от предыдущего админа сервер, на котором один из сайтов работает с Firebird, и не могу этот самый Firebird запустить после ребута сервера. В /usr/bin нашел fb_config

Как его запустить?
С линуксом знаком поверхностно

```
  fb_bindir=/usr/lib64/firebird/bin-classic
  fb_libdir=/usr/lib64
  fb_incdir=/usr/include/firebird
  fb_udfdir=/usr/lib64/firebird/UDF
  fb_sbindir=/usr/sbin
  fb_confdir=/etc/firebird
  fb_docdir=/usr/share/doc/firebird
  fb_sampledir=/usr/share/doc/firebird/examples
  fb_sampledbdir=/var/lib/firebird/data/
  fb_helpdir=/var/lib/firebird/system/
  fb_intldir=/usr/lib64/firebird/intl
  fb_miscdir=/usr/lib64/firebird/misc
  fb_securedbdir=/var/lib/firebird/system
  fb_msgdir=/var/lib/firebird/system
  fb_logdir=/var/log/firebird
  fb_glockdir=/var/run/firebird
  fb_pluginsdir=/usr/lib64/firebird/plugins-classic

  fb_cflags="-I$fb_incdir"
  fb_libs="-L$fb_libdir -lfbclient"
  fb_embedlibs="-L$fb_libdir -lfbembed"

  BuildVersion=2.5.3.26778
  PackageVersion=0
  CpuType=amd64
```

Comment: Дмитрий, отформатируйте вопрос пожалуйста. Читать такое трудно.